# Find and delete categories dont have product

Tags: mysql

I have a table with in `offer_category` and `product` tables. I want to make a query that find `offer_categories` dont have `product`. On `product` i have `170k rows` and on `offer_category` table `3.6k`

my query:

```
  SELECT offer_category.title,product.name,offer_category.id FROM 
   `offer_category` left join product on product.category_id = 
    offer_category.id where product.id is null
```

when i want to run it , my browser running (i can see the circle that looping) but about 10 min not response anything.

How can i make that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query seems to be fine:

```
  select oc.title, p.name, oc.id
  from  `offer_category` oc left join
        product p
        on p.category_id = oc.id
  where p.id is null;
```

(I just rewrote it with table aliases to make it more readable.)

The problem would seem to be performance (or a hanging connection to the database).  To improve performance, you want an index on `product(category_id, id)`:

```
create index product_category_id_id on product(category_id, id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   offer_category
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT product.category_id
         FROM   product
         WHERE  product.category_id = offer_category.category_id
       )
```

Comment: @gvee.. does it fetches info from product table?

Comment: i dont understand , its working and working but not response anything. i try it from ssh but still not response anything. i need to wait ?

Comment: @AvinashKothamasu why would it need to? " I want to make a query that find offer_categories dont have product" <-- the product details would always be a NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Well you query is correct so I don't think there is any problem there. I wouldn't do the latter answer since it will do a select for each row in offer_category.

It seems like you are just pulling a large amount of data over the network so it is taking a long time to download to your browser.

Try running this on your server via mysql workbench or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

There are thousands of records in both tables,so obviously you have to wait some more time.
Try it in my.ini change below fields value:

```
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
```

OR Try to run this query from mysql command prompt directly.This would be better.

AND apply indexes to your foreign key fields fields  product.category_id and offer_category.category_id